# global variable values set within fs.readfile are not reatained outside the function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Array values logged at the end `console.log(arr)` are empty;

```
const fs = require("fs");
    const fss = require("fs");
    
      const data = fs.readFileSync("files_list.txt","utf-8");
      const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    let arr = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const val = lines[i];
      const startLength = val.indexOf(';')+1;
      const endLength = lines[i].length;
    const hour = val.substring(startLength,endLength);
    const fileName = val.substring(0,endLength-2);
    fs.readFile("available.txt", function (err, dt){
      if (err) throw err;
      if(dt.includes(fileName)){
        var r = {
          filName:fileName,
          batchTiming:hour,
          status:'OK'
        };
        arr.push(r);
    }
    else
    {
        var r = {
        filName:fileName,
        batchTiming:hour,
        status:'OK'
      };
      arr.push(r);
    }
    
    });
    console.log(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to log the contents of `arr` BEFORE anything has been put in it.  `fs.readFile()` is non-blocking and asynchronous so your `console.log(arr)` runs before `fs.readFile()` calls its callback.

The ONLY place you can use the results of `fs.readFile()` is in the callback itself or in a function you call from within that callback and pass the result to that function.

P.S. This code is a little odd because you're reading the same file over and over again inside a `for` loop.  That doesn't really make sense.  You can read the content once before your loop and then use the content over and over again inside the `for` loop.